# Http header not updating

Tags: .htaccess, http-headers, amazon-elb

I have two EC2 servers sitting behing an AWS classic load balancer. I am trying to update http headers but changes are not going through. Currently headers dont have caching and i want to setup cache for images/css. I have all the directives placed in htaccess file but headers are not gettimg updated.

If i access the servers without ELB then headers get updated with values that i have set up in htaccess file so ELB is not letting headers updated.

Any suggestion how this can be acheived.

```
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 3 days"
    ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-ico "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"

    
    Header unset ETag
    Header unset Pragma
    Header unset Cache-Control
    Header unset Last-Modified
    Header append Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    #Header set Last-modified "Sun, 26 May 2019 10:10:10 GMT"
```

Comment: The only really plausible explanation here is that you are somehow adding headers that aren't syntactically valid, so the balancer strips them, but that isn't a documented behavior, so what you describe is difficult to explain. Please show what you added to `.htaccess`.

Comment: Also perhaps post your response payload/headers for with and without ELB